# Android SeekBar Length Not Matching layout_width Value

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-view, android-seekbar

I'm trying to make a seekbar with a harcoded width in a layout, however, once the seekbar's harcoded width value surpasses a certain value the seekbar's width will not reflect the value I set. For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <SeekBar
        android:rotation="270"
        android:id="@+id/volumeBar"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_margin="1px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent = "true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

produces a short seekbar, as it should since the width dictates it should only be 50dp long. Here's the layout:
[image]

Now, when I change the layout_width to 300dp I see a clipped seekbar that is certainly not 300dp long. Heres the file and layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <SeekBar
        android:rotation="270"
        android:id="@+id/volumeBar"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_margin="1px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent = "true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

**Note:** It appears as if the seekbar is limited to the width of the relative layout (the red rectangle) and anytime the length of the seekbar (specified by android:layout_width) would exceed the width of the RelativeLayout it's length is capped. **How can I make my seekbar obey my desired hardcoded length?**

Edit: I've included the parent activity's xml file below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:keepScreenOn="true">

    <LinearLayout    
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.25"
        android:background="#ffdd4c4f"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:id="@+id/toolbarGestureOverlay" >
        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
    </LinearLayout>  

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:layout_weight="3.75">
    <com.example.project.Multitouch
        android:id="@+id/fretBoard"  
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#3EF20C"/>
    </LinearLayout>    
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I got the same problem. Did you get any solution !

Comment: Same here! Any solution?

Comment: I haven't found a solution.

Comment: Looking for the same thing. After 9 year, there is no a good solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with

```
   <SeekBar
        android:rotation="270"
        android:id="@+id/volumeBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent = "true"/>
```

Comment: Did not work. The seekbar still appears as it does in the second picture I posted.

Comment: Not working. Still looking for a real solution.